Error ensuring domain-wide principals: Entitlement Name too long
I am facing an issue on SharePoint administration page, I cannot access to the list of pending API Access requests because of this error popup:

Error ensuring domain-wide principals: Entitlement Name too long. Entitlement: [EncodingVersion=2,EntitlementId=39cb2f57-403c-497d-abcc-f6148c303db0,IsDisabled=False,Name=Accedere all'entità di sicurezza dell'applicazione Web di estendibilità del client di SharePoint Online,Description=Consente all'applicazione di accedere all'entità di sicurezza dell'applicazione Web di estendibilità del client di SharePoint Online per conto dell'utente connesso.,Definition=,ClaimValue=user_impersonation,Origin=,ResourceScopeType=Personal,IsPrivate=False,UserConsentDisplayName=Accedere all'entità di sicurezza dell'applicazione Web di estendibilità del client di SharePoint Online,UserConsentDescription=Consente all'applicazione di accedere all'entità di sicurezza dell'applicazione Web di estendibilità del client di SharePoint Online per conto dell'utente.,DirectAccessGrantTypes=,ImpersonationAccessGrantTypes=[Impersonator=Application,Impersonated=User,skipValueChangeEvent=False],skipValueChangeEvent=False,EntitlementCategory=Default,DependentMicrosoftGraphPermissions=,IsPreauthzOnlyDirectAccessGrant=False,IsPreauthzOnlyImpersonationGrant=False]. paramName: Entitlement.Name, paramValue: , objectType: Microsoft.Online.DirectoryServices.Entitlement

Furthermore, I've noticed that the application: SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal is not created automatically when installing the web part on SharePoint with requests on Graph (it has always worked before today).
NOTICE: "Accedere all'entità di sicurezza dell'applicazione Web di estendibilità del client di SharePoint Online" (the name too long issue) is the Italian translation of "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal".
The error looks like this but slightly different. PS: I've also tried this solution but didn't work.
I attach an image of the error:

